# White House tours on weekends?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, washington-dc, government-buildings

As a US citizen, to tour the White House you have to go through your member of Congress. I did so, through their website, and they had a field asking for the dates I'd like to do the tour. My tentative game plan is to be in DC over the weekend.

Does the White House conduct tours on Saturday / Sunday?

Comment: Good catch! It's the weekend before Thanksgiving, Nov 21-22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saturday they are available, but doesn't look like they are available on Sunday:

From [Whitehouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/participate/tours-and-events):

> Public tour requests must be submitted through one's Member of Congress.  These self-guided tours are available from 7:30 a.m. to 11:30 a.m. Tuesday through Thursday, 7:30 a.m. to 1:30 p.m. Fridays and Saturdays (excluding federal holidays or unless otherwise noted).  Tour hours will be extended when possible based on the official White House schedule. Tours are scheduled on a first come, first served basis. Requests can be submitted up to six months in advance and no less than 21 days in advance. You are encouraged to submit your request as early as possible as a limited number of spaces are available. All White House tours are free of charge.  (Please note that White House tours may be subject to last minute cancellation.)
>
> If you wish to visit the White House and are a citizen of a foreign country, please contact your embassy in Washington, DC for assistance in submitting a tour request.